# Parallel storage of data samples with different length in one structure

Tags: matlab, structure, reshape, cell-array

I need to collect samples, which are pairs of vectors `X`, `Y` in a structure `data`, with fields `X` and `Y`. I need to run many simulations and in the end my structure looks like `data(i).X`, `data(i).Y` with `i` the i-th simulation. I need a structure because not all the simulations have the same length.

I can easily use a loop and run one simulation at a time, but I want to improve the speed by running many simulations in parallel.

I tried by first initializing the data structure

```
data = struct( ...
    'X', nan(dim_x, maxsteps), ...
    'Y', nan(dim_y, maxsteps), ...
    );
data = repmat(data, maxsimul, 1);
```

but I don't know how to update it at each time step. I would like to do something like

```
[data(ongoing).s(:,step)] = deal(squeeze(num2cell(x_samples,[1,maxsimul])));
[data(~ongoing).s(:,step)] = deal([]);
```

where `ongoing` is a boolean vector to know which simulations are still running.
But of course it doesn't work. Is it possible to do what I want?

Alternatively, I could use 3d matrices initialized with `NaN` and fill them at each time step

```
X = nan(dim_x, maxsteps, maxsimul);
Y = nan(dim_y, maxsteps, maxsimul);

X(:,step,ongoing) = x_sample;
Y(:,step,ongoing) = y_sample;
```

After all simulations are done I transform the matrices by

```
data = struct( ...
    'X', squeeze(num2cell(X,[1 2])), ...
    'X', squeeze(num2cell(X,[1 2])), ...
    );
```

However, I still have to obtain a final structure like the one described above and I don't know how to filter out the `NaN`.

Example

```
x1 = [1 1 1 nan nan; 1 2 1 nan nan];
x2 = [4 nan nan nan nan; 1 nan nan nan nan];
X = zeros(2,5,2);
X(:,:,1) = x1;
X(:,:,2) = x2;

y1 = [12 41 1 nan nan];
y2 = [11 nan nan nan nan];
Y = zeros(1,5,2);
Y(:,:,1) = y1;
Y(:,:,2) = y2;
```

And I need

```
data(1).X = [1 1 1; 1 2 1];
data(2).X = [4; 1];
data(1).Y = [12 41 1];
data(2).Y = [11];
```

Any idea to accomplish what I need? It's ok to use any of the above approaches, that is either by creating the structure step by step, or by transforming 3d matrices.

Comment: Change your sequential loop to a `parfor` loop, that'd work. Just make sure you predefine all storage containers.

Comment: @Adriaan I was already using a `parfor` but if I parallelize as described in my question I can be 10x faster (already tried, but I cannot use the data structure since it is not in my desired format).